# Word to describe the unknown future

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a summary for a novel I am writing, but I cannot think of the word I am looking for.
I am looking for a word that describes something will happen in the future but nobody knows anything about this event. The event is not bad necessarily, it could be good or bad. mostly a neutral meaning.

"Dorthy did not know of the **Wicked witches intent to burn scarecrow or the red shoes being able to take her home**"
Wicked witch was bad.
The red shoes was good.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: The uncertainty of the future.

Comment: "Wiched witches" should be "Wicked Witch's"

Comment: I'm not sure I get this. Is there such a thing as a known future? Do some people actually know the future?

Answer (score 2):

To combine the concept that *something* will happen in the unknowable *future* into one (neutral) word, I suggest nominalizing an adjective, for example:

**the unforeseen**

> **unforeseen** (adj.)
>
> Not anticipated or expected : not foreseen : UNEXPECTED [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unforeseen)

---

> Sure with computer technology and careful analysis, you could predict
> the outcome of many things, but **the unforeseen** will always remain
> so, not even the computers can tell of that. [Desmond Silpatt; *The
> Genius and His Lover*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Genius_and_His_Lover/TTPNDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=no%20one%20could%20predict%20%22the%20unforeseen%22&pg=PT11&printsec=frontcover)

> Individual agency notwithstanding, we must always reconcile with
> uncertainty,  **the unforeseen**, and the unpredictable when we
> predict. [Johnny Saldana; *Thinking Qualitatively*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Thinking_Qualitatively/JluNBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=no%20one%20could%20predict%20%22the%20unforeseen%22&pg=PT114&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

- [Vagaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/vagaries): "unexpected events or changes that cannot be controlled and can influence a situation". Also synonyms like "uncertainties."
- [Happenstance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/happenstance): An occurrence that is controlled by random chance. Not necessarily the shade of meaning that you're looking for, since it emphasizes randomness rather than uncertainty.
- Gamble (noun): If you want to emphasize that the subject is aware of multiple outcomes and has strong reason to hope for a particular one.
- Idioms like "on a knife's edge," "in the balance," "shrouded in mystery."

Answer (score -1):

Further nominalisations of adjectives that work in ecpressing the future, with its aspected of being unknown are:

> The unpredictable

> The unanticipated

> The unexpected

And possibly

> The unfathomable

Though I prefer this with the word future attached, as in:

> The unfathomable future.

Thus your sample sentence would run:

> Dorothy did not *anticipate* the Wicked Witch's intent to burn the scarecrow or the red shoes being able to take her home.

Or

> Dorothy did not *expect* the Wicked Witch's intent to burn the scarecrow or the red shoes being able to take her home.

Or

> Dorothy did not *predict* the Wicked Witch's intent to burn the scarecrow or the red shoes being able to take her home.

Or

> Dorothy did not *fathom* the Wicked Witch's intent to burn the scarecrow or the red shoes being able to take her home.